# How to change border colour of text box with rounded corners extender attached.

Tags: asp.net, ajax, text

How do you change the border colour of a text box (on focus and on blur) with an extender attached to it?

I tried some JavaScript which worked on the text box by itself, but not with rounded corners extender attached.

I don't have the JS on me right now, but if you wat the code, let me know and I'll add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is use jQuery to select the  element for the rounded corners then manipulate its background color.

1. Include the [jQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js) script in your page
2. In your onblur() and onfocus() event handlers, change the background color using the following syntax. You can use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to obtain the  element ID (see attached screenshot). [e.g. ctl00_SampleContent_Panel1]

   $("#ctl00_SampleContent_Panel1").css('background-color', 'blue');

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not clear but use the below code in your stylesheet
to change the border color of textbox onfocus

input[type=text]:focus {border:#00F solid 2px}